# Very basic example of pgfpictureboxed in Beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

According to [the userguide](http://mixing.coas.oregonstate.edu/links/latex_files/pgfuserguide.pdf) (§2.1, p. 6), the `pgfpictureboxed`-environment works as follows:

```
\begin{pgfpictureboxed}{〈lower left x〉}{〈lower left y〉}{〈upper right x〉}{〈upper right y〉}
    〈environmentcontents〉                                                      
\end{pgfpictureboxed}
```

My (obviously wrong) interpretation is that these parameters set the absolute position of the picturedbox in the surface.

Thus, I expect in the example below the following:
- In frame 1 I should see a box with left corner in (0cm,0cm) and right corner in (5cm,5cm)
- In frame 2 I should see a box with left corner in (4cm,0cm) and right corner in (9cm,5cm). That is, a box of the same size, but shifted four centimeters to the right

But what is generated are exactly the same boxes. Why?

Example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgf}

\begin{document}

\frame{\frametitle{Example pgfpictureboxed}

\begin{pgfpictureboxed}{0cm}{0cm}{5cm}{5cm}
\end{pgfpictureboxed}

}

\frame{\frametitle{Example pgfpictureboxed cords 4,0,9,5}

\begin{pgfpictureboxed}{4cm}{0cm}{9cm}{5cm}
\end{pgfpictureboxed}

}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The coordinates you're giving are not relative to the `beamer`-frame, but to the `pdf`-picture coordinate.
That means if you set `〈lower left x〉 = 1cm` and `〈lower left y〉 = 2cm`, then the point in the bottm left corner of your picture will the the point that has the coordinates `{1cm, 2cm}` *in the referential of you picture*.

But this picture will be inserter *as regular text* in your slide, that means according to the rest of the content of your slide.

---

See this MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgf}

\begin{document}

    \frame{\frametitle{Example pgfpictureboxed}
        Some dummy text
        \begin{pgfpictureboxed}{0cm}{0cm}{5cm}{5cm}
            \pgfline{\pgforigin}{\pgfpoint{5cm}{5cm}}
        \end{pgfpictureboxed}

    }

    \frame{\frametitle{Example pgfpictureboxed cords 4,0,9,5}
        Hello World
        \begin{pgfpictureboxed}{4cm}{0cm}{9cm}{5cm}
            \pgfline{\pgforigin}{\pgfpoint{5cm}{5cm}}
        \end{pgfpictureboxed}

    }
\end{document}
```

[image]